# in a content editable paragraph how can i make each word as a span?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning react right now. I want to create a notes app with a content editable paragraph. One of the features is that the user can make the text inside of it **bold**, *italic* or underlined.

i think it wouldve been a lot better if i could just turn each word into the contenteditable paragraph as a span(and later make each individual span bold and so on, as needed) though i cant figure out how.

My current solution leads to spans wrapped in spans which might be unnecessary.
Another issue I've encountered is when mixing overlapping parts with different styles. E.g. having this sentence: James has an apple. I can make the part "an apple" bold: James has **an apple**. With my solution I can't additionally make the part "has an" **italic** because the two spans would not mix together like this: `<span1>has <span2>an</span1> apple</span2>`

This is my code so far:

```
import "./App.css";
export default function App() {
  function formatText(command) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    const span = document.createElement("span");

    if (command === "bold") {
      span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else if (command === "italic") {
      span.style.fontStyle = "italic";
    } else if (command === "underline") {
      span.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }

    range.surroundContents(span);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
  }

  return (
    <div className="textarea-container">
      <div className="textarea-btns">
        <button type="button" id="bold-btn" onClick={() => formatText("bold")}>
          B
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="italicize-btn"
          onClick={() => formatText("italic")}
        >
          I
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="underline-btn"
          onClick={() => formatText("underline")}
        >
          U
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="textarea-padding">
        <p contentEditable className="textarea"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What could be a working solution for my problem?

Comment: To make bold and italic, you can make each span separately then no need to merge spans